# ElasticSearch query returns wrong results

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm relatively new to ElasticSearch and encountered this issue which I can't seem to get why.

So for this particular field, it seems to be treating all the values to be zero, even though the individual records are non-zero values. This only seems to happen to this number field and not other similar fields (such as cpu pct, mem pct etc)

The records only show when I query for records that have 'system.filesystem.used.pct == 0', whereas none of them show when I do something like 'system.filesystem.used.pct > 0'.

[image: Kibana Discover Results]

I also did the querying in the dev tools in kibana like so, yet I don't get any results:

```
GET metricbeat-*/_search{
  "query": {
    "range":{
      "system.filesystem.used.pct":{
         "gt":0
        }
       }
     }
}
```

[image]

However, if I did this, I will get all non-zero results, just like in discover:

```
GET metricbeat-*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "system.filesytem.used.pct":0
     }
  }
}
```

[image: Sample match]

Comment: Maybe the mapping for this value is an integer? so 0.145 is indexed as 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Ron Serruya, there is a mapping issue. The mapping for `system.filesytem.used.pct` is detected as to be of `integer` type. Since, you are getting the expected search results for `cpu.pct` field, the mapping of `cpu.pct`, must have been of `float` type

**CASE 1:**

If you index the two sample data as (in the same order)

```
{
  "count": 0.45
}
{
  "count": 0
}
```

Then `float` data type is detected by elasticsearch (if you are using dynamic mapping). this is because the detection of the field type depends on the first data that you have inserted in the field.

**CASE 2:**

Now, if you index the data in this order

```
{
  "count": 0
}
{
  "count": 0.45
}
```

Here elasticsearch will detect `count` to be of `long` data type.

---

You need to recreate the index, with the new index mapping, reindex the data and then run the search query on `system.filesytem.used.pct`

Modified index mapping will be

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "system": {
        "properties": {
          "filesytem": {
            "properties": {
              "used": {
                "properties": {
                  "pct": {
                    "type": "float"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I have checked the mapping and indeed it is of type long instead of float.